# Updating field in Active Record

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I want to write a query like

```
    "Update table tbl_name set amount = amount + 100 where id = 10";
```

I found no documentation in CI Active Record library, Is it possible to do such query using acitve record?

Looking forward for your responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the model function:

```
function update($id) {
     $this->db->set('amount', 'amount+100', FALSE)
     $this->db->where('id ', $id);
     $this->db->update('tbl_name');
}
```

You can read the CI Active Record [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by using `$this->db->set();`

try this

```
$this->db->set('amount', 'amount+100', FALSE)
$this->db->where('id ', '10');
$this->db->update('tbl_name');
```